# How does Chrome or any other browser use Public Suffix List?

Tags: cookies, setcookie, samesite, public-suffix-list

Just curious, Chrome or any other browser does not allow to set cookies present in public suffix list. Domains like .github.io or .compute.aws.amazon.com are a few examples present on the list.

1. How does it stay in sync with the updates on the public suffix list?
2. If I add my domain to Public Suffix List, How long would it take for browser systems to get updated?
3. What about the cookies that are already set on domains which are lately, added to PSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Chrome and Firefox include a copy of the Public Suffix List in each build. You can find this for Chromium [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/net/base/registry_controlled_domains/effective_tld_names.dat), and for Firefox [here](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat).

It looks like Firefox's copy is updated about once a week. Chromium's appears to be updated less frequently. As of right now, the last update to Chromium's list was 6 months ago.

Comment: you missed answering this one `What about the cookies that are already set on domains which are lately, added to PSL?`